# Convert 14 digit datetime object to POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have an array of datetime objects created in python, that I'd like to read into R as a POSIXct. For example, the 14 digit datetime object looks like:

```
736908.51782407
```

I believe this is the datetime

```
2018, 8, 2, 12, 25, 55
```

But I'm not sure how to convert the numerical datetime to POSIXct in R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 14 digit time value appears to the number of days since `0001-01-01`.  If so, we can convert it to seconds since `0001-01-01` and then use `as.POSIXct()`:

```
val <- 736908.51782407
val <- val * 24 * 60 * 60
as.POSIXct(val, origin="0001-01-01")

[1] "2017-08-03 14:25:39 CEST"
```

### Demo

The output does not line up exactly with what you are expecting.  I don't Python well enough to comment.  There could also be timezone issues with `as.POSXIct`, but this answer seems to be on the right track.

Comment: I think you're definitely on the right path, though I get 2018 instead of 2017 using your code. Shifting to `"UTC"` timezone also lines it up closer again.

Comment: @thelatemail I don't know if the R API were ever intended to do calculations going back to the year zero.  There can be edge cases along the way, such as missing days, as well as rounding error.